# How to find a general solution for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ + $e^{2x−3y}$ = −$e^x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ + $e^{2x−3y}$ = −$e^x$

Do I use integrating factors?

Answer (score 0):

Start by putting $z=y+e^x$. That gives $z'=-e^{2x-3z+3e^x}$. Multiply both sides by $e^{3z}$ to get $e^{3z}z'=-e^{2x+3e^x}$.

Integrating $e^{3z}=\frac{1}{3}e^{3e^x}-e^{x+3e^x}+C$. Taking logs, $z=\frac{1}{3}\ln(\frac{1}{3}e^{3e^x}-e^{x+3e^x}+C)$ and so $y=-e^x+\frac{1}{3}\ln(\frac{1}{3}e^{3e^x}-e^{x+3e^x}+C)$.